# Can you pass scss file as prop to another react component to use?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I created a reusable table (DataTable) that can be imported and used inside a wrapper:

```
import styles from './styles.scss';
function TableTest() {
  return (
    <DataTable
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      withFirstAndLast
      defaultSortName="lastrefreshed"
      defaultSortOrder="asc"
      noDataText={noDataSign()}
      fullstyle={styles}
    />
  );
}
```

I want others to be able to import their own scss files into the table to override the table's default style page. I allow this by passing the classname of the scss file into the classname of the div of the original table:

```
 render() {
    const classname = styles['datatable-container'];
    const classnameimport = this.styleimport['datatable-container'];
    console.log(classname, this.styleimport);
    return (
      <div className={classnameimport || classname}>
```

Is there a better way to do this or should this work? So far it isn't

Answer (score 0):

The way CSS styles typically work is that you assign a fixed class name to an element. Then anyone can add that class name to their own CSS or SCSS file to override the styles on that element.

If you want to allow users to add their own class names, then add a `className` prop or something like that. Then the user passes the class name as a prop to your component and uses the same class name in their styles.